# Accurate Bounding Box From Geography Polygon

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Given a table with a column

```
polygon geography(Polygon,4326)
```

I want to add another column

```
bounding_box geography(Polygon,4326)
```

that accurately represents the bounding box of the `polygon` column. The functions `ST_Extent` and `ST_Envelope` create bounding boxes, but they only accept and return geometries, so using them means that the `bounding_box` assignment looks something like `bounding_box = geography::ST_Envelope(geometry::polygon)`. I am concerned about the loss of accuracy. If I do a point-in-poly query on `bounding_box` before doing an `ST_Covers` query on `polygon`, is it possible I will not get some hits that I should be getting because the `bounding_box` loses some of the size it should have in the conversion back and forth between types?

So my questions are:

- Is there any accuracy lost in `geography::ST_Envelope(geometry::polygon)`?
- If so, what is a more accurate solution?

P.S. The reason for the `bounding_box` column is so it can be indexed. The values in the `polygon` column are too big to be indexed. The point-in-poly query would look like this:
`find_point && bounding_box AND ST_Covers(polygon, find_point)`
where `find_point` is of type `geography(Point,4326)`.

Comment: "The values in the polygon column are too big to be indexed". What error are you getting then?

Comment: What do you mean by "too big to be indexed"? Spatially?

Comment: It's been a week or so since I tried it, but I was getting some kind of error when i tried to insert into the `polygon` column while it was indexed. By "too big" I mean "too many points." The error message I got gave me the impression that an object that consumed as much memory as the polygon I was trying to insert was too big to be indexed.

Comment: The memory limit of 2GB for a geometry is set by PostgreSQL. A spatial index is not limited by the number of points in any geometry. You would need to dig through to get the error message before making assumptions and workarounds.